# does oversampling affect the correlation? if yes, how to avoid that?

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, python, finance

I have a data set of retuns from a hedge fund, but to evaluate the performance of this fund, risk management wants daily data. So I have to transform those monthly to daily data (say 5 columns, 5 differents HF) by keeping some statistical properties the same among them like correlation, or pdf of each fund should be the same when moving from monthly to daily. One column is my target variable and all the other are my feature. I have computed correlation between my target and all the other feature and then I made linear regression and got my betas and R2.

Now my question is more theoretical. if I oversample to daily data (I used a linear interpolation) and compute again correlation, betas and R2, they have changed a lot. Can anybody explain me why that happens? is correlation affected by oversampling?I might expect my betas to change because I have much more data after oversampling and so the R2, but not really the correlation if the size of my monthly data was already quite large. Also, is it possible to oversample two time series by forcing them to have the same correlation as they had before being oversampled?

Comment: Why do you "oversample" (really, interpolate, and what you are doing is not resampling so I removed that tag.)

Comment: Could you also include some plots of your data before and after interpolation/oversampling?

Answer (score 2):

You should really have given some more information, maybe a plot of your data, and especialy **why are you doing this?**. What you are doing is not oversampling, it is linear interpolation. Think about what happens between two sample points, when you for both x and y linearly interpolate. **Between those two sample points the correlation coefficient will be $\pm 1$!**

So it should not be a surprise that the correlation changes.

Comment: thanks! the reason why I am doing this is because I have a data set of retuns from a hedge fund, but to evaluate the performance of this fund, risk management wants daily data. So I have to transform those monthly to daily data (say 5 columns, 5 differents HF) by keeping some statistical properties the same among them like correlation, or pdf of each fund should be the same when moving from monthly to daily

Comment: Please add all of this background information to the post as an edit. Not everybody reads comments!